# How to alert a block using overlays?

Tags: beamer, overlays

For discussion I have th following M(N)WE:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{Frankfurt}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{ABC}

% Just to verify that alert is working in general
\begin{itemize}[<+->]
 \item a
 \item<+-| alert@2> b
 \item c
\end{itemize}

\begin{block}<alert@2>{Test block}
This block should be alerted in overlay 2.
\end{block}

\begin{alertblock}{Alerted block}
Example of an alert block.
\end{alertblock}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

I think what I want to do is straight forward: On the second page, I want the `Test block` to be rendered as an alerted one like the one below it.

The beamer user guide states under 9.6.3 Action specifications:

> `alert` alters the item or block.

Is this by intention or a bug or do I miss a point that is missing in my MWE?
Do I need to wrap things in an `\alt` structure and retype the whole content of the block?

Comment: I will do `\only<1>{unalerted block}\only<2>{alerted block}`

Comment: I guess I would have expected the same behavior than you. Possibly a bug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those stumbling over this thread, I opened as well a [issue on github](https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/issues/596).

To summarize the discussion there:

- The alert action specification for blocks is not meant to produce an alert block but to alert items within the block.
- The simplest solution to alert a single block on a slide is most probably to change the color on that overlay:

```
\only<2>{\setbeamercolor{block title}{use=alerted text,fg=white,bg=alerted text.fg!75!black}}
\begin{block}{...}
% ...
\end{block}
```